# How can I pass an array of SCSS files to gulp, to be compiled down?

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I want to be able to specify a list of SCSS files in an array (unfortunately I can't do this by storing them in a directory and just globbing).

I am envisioning something sort of like:

```
    myfiles = ['header.scss', 'content.scss', 'footer.scss'];

    gulp.src_from_array( { base: '/sass/sources/', file_array: myfiles } )
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
        .pipe(notify({
            onLast: true,
            message: "Sass compiled successfully <%= file.relative %>",
        })
    );
```

The idea is that it would process the SCSS files specified in the array, then poop out one CSS file (and a sourcemap).

How can I accomplish this? I was thinking maybe something with [gulp-foreach](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-foreach), or [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if) but I can't quite work out how that would be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand what you're looking for, but can't you just use gulp.src, seeing as it [supports an array of globs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options)?

So, in your example, that would be:

```
myfiles = ['/sass/sources/header.scss', '/sass/sources/content.scss', '/sass/sources/footer.scss'];

gulp.src(myfiles)
    .pipe...
```

Another way would be to have a SCSS files which imports all the other ones.

Comment: Brilliant. Does the job perfectly. Thanks!